# Action hooked on wp_enqueue_scripts running twice

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I disabled all plugins on my wordpress and keept only my very simple theme active. On functions.php I let running the following code:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    // Omitted some code - Here I just call a custom function to print logs
    wp_debug_backtrace_summary(); // Just indicating that I call this function on log

    // The script exists and is correctly added to the frontend
    wp_enqueue_script( 'main-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/scripts.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
}, 101 );
```

On the log, I get that this function run twice - you can see above two payloads from `wp_debug_backtrace_summary()`:

```
[2020-02-10 20:58:37 - ...\wp-content\themes\storms-theme\services\storms-assets.php at "backtrace" on line 42] 
    == Funcao de teste ===================================
    Array
(
    [0] => StormsFramework\Helper::backtrace
    [1] => {closure}
    [2] => WP_Hook->apply_filters
    [3] => WP_Hook->do_action
    [4] => do_action('wp_enqueue_scripts')
    [5] => wp_enqueue_scripts
    [6] => WP_Hook->apply_filters
    [7] => WP_Hook->do_action
    [8] => do_action('wp_head')
    [9] => wp_head
    [10] => require('/themes/storms-theme/template-parts/head.php')
    [11] => load_template
    [12] => locate_template
    [13] => get_template_part
    [14] => require_once('/themes/storms-theme/header.php')
    [15] => load_template
    [16] => locate_template
    [17] => get_header
    [18] => include('/themes/storms-theme/page.php')
    [19] => require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php')
    [20] => require('wp-blog-header.php')
)


=====================================================================

[2020-02-10 20:58:37 - ...\wp-content\themes\storms-theme\services\storms-assets.php at "backtrace" on line 42] 
    == Funcao de teste ===================================
    Array
(
    [0] => StormsFramework\Helper::backtrace
    [1] => {closure}
    [2] => WP_Hook->apply_filters
    [3] => WP_Hook->do_action
    [4] => do_action('wp_enqueue_scripts')
    [5] => wp_enqueue_scripts
    [6] => WP_Hook->apply_filters
    [7] => WP_Hook->do_action
    [8] => do_action('wp_head')
    [9] => wp_head
    [10] => require('/themes/storms-theme/template-parts/head.php')
    [11] => load_template
    [12] => locate_template
    [13] => get_template_part
    [14] => require_once('/themes/storms-theme/header.php')
    [15] => load_template
    [16] => locate_template
    [17] => get_header
    [18] => include('/themes/storms-theme/index.php')
    [19] => require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php')
    [20] => require('wp-blog-header.php')
)
```

I notice the item 18 on both backtrace are different:

```
[18] => include('/themes/storms-theme/page.php')
[18] => include('/themes/storms-theme/index.php')
```

If I comment the code line that enqueue the script `wp_enqueue_script( 'main-script', ... )` The payload I get says my function run only once!

```
[2020-02-10 21:13:21 - ...\wp-content\themes\storms-theme\services\storms-assets.php at "backtrace" on line 42] 
    == Funcao de teste ===================================
    Array
(
    [0] => StormsFramework\Helper::backtrace
    [1] => {closure}
    [2] => WP_Hook->apply_filters
    [3] => WP_Hook->do_action
    [4] => do_action('wp_enqueue_scripts')
    [5] => wp_enqueue_scripts
    [6] => WP_Hook->apply_filters
    [7] => WP_Hook->do_action
    [8] => do_action('wp_head')
    [9] => wp_head
    [10] => require('/themes/storms-theme/template-parts/head.php')
    [11] => load_template
    [12] => locate_template
    [13] => get_template_part
    [14] => require_once('/themes/storms-theme/header.php')
    [15] => load_template
    [16] => locate_template
    [17] => get_header
    [18] => include('/themes/storms-theme/page.php')
    [19] => require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php')
    [20] => require('wp-blog-header.php')
)
```

I have no idea what is wrong here. Why is running twice?

Comment: Try logging the request URL, just to see if the double entries originate from the same page or different request/URL. But it seems like there were two simultaneous requests made to the site..

Comment: @SallyCJ Good call! Just did and the first call is to my actual page ('/') and there is another to some .js.map (/wp-content/themes/my-theme/assets/js/collapse.js.map). Not sure what is this asset, since is a .map. Why is hitting the Wordpress?

Comment: .map is a source map for JS files that can be used to help debug issues with scripts that are compiled from other scripts. There's likely a reference to it in that JS file somewhere. If that file isn't actually present, then it will 404, so WordPress will load its 404 page, which will trigger another request, which explains why you're seeing two log entries.

Comment: Perfect! You solve my problem! Thank you very much!